# Failed BPF matching on iptables PREROUTING

Tags: linux, iptables

I am working on an iptables rule to match a range of MAC addresses from within the PREROUTING table; my implementation uses the BPF matching option from iptables-extensions. Here is an example of an expression that should match drop a MAC address of aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff, matching all bytes.

```
((ether[6:4] & 0xffffffff) = (0xaabbccdd & 0xffffffff)) && ((ether[10:2] & 0xffff) = (0xeeff & 0xffff))
```

Based on the output of `tcpdump -nn`, this expression seems to be correct.

When sent through `tcpdump -ddd` or the `nfbpf_compile` utility, the resulting bytecode is used to create an iptables rule.

```
iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -i br0 -m bpf --bytecode "BYTECODE OUTPUT" -j DROP
```

My issue is that when this rule is made in the PREROUTING table (which needs to be done), packets are only infrequently dropped; most packets make it through the filter. If the rule is made in the INPUT table, packets seem to be blocked successfully.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you can't use BPF matching for this, at least not from within iptables.

Using BPF matching for the ethernet header is only possible when using a link type of RAW such as on a TAP device. When using a physical device that only supports EN10MB, the Ethernet header is not included.

If you want to implement this functionality and you need to use iptables, you'll need to create a TAP (or similar) dummy interface that you can see the header info from.